# GridBagLayout: changes alignment after adding checkbox

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I have two classes which creates two different dialog box. Both the classes have same code, except one has additional lines of code, which creates a checkbox

first Class, with Checkbox

[image]

Second Class, without Checkbox

[image]

There is slight alignment difference in "save" button. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to adjust the row height as the checkbox was taller than the row and was pushing the third row downward( Thanks to Ingrid Biery). so I changed the 2nd row height from 25 to 30 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're using fixed row and column sizes? One of the great features of GridBagLayout is its ability to center/align and fill. This also tends to make things look better on different screen sizes, different fonts, etc.

To answer your specific question, my guess is that the checkbox is taller than the row you're putting it into, pushing the next row down.

When I debug GBL, I often set row/column background colors to different things and print out (or view in a debugger) sizes of the things I'm trying to fit into the container.

Comment: There is no reason and I am new to GridBagLayout. I can certainly change it to more convenient manner. can you point me one easy example. How can I set background to debug

Comment: I'm not sure an easy example of GBL exists. But I'm sure you could search for tutorials. It's confusing and tricky, but if you want your layouts to move in a logical way that you control, there is no substitute. It's been awhile since I've done this, and I see that there is no way to set the background colors directly. I think I used JPanels which can be made to take the shape of the container they're in. It's a good way to play around with GridBagLayout and see what will happen when you resize your windows.

Comment: I fixed it, on your suggestion, I increased the row height of 2nd row from 25 to 30 and it worked. Thanks